# OpenCV for Windows 8(metro style apps)

Tags: image-processing, powershell, opencv, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

OpenCV 2.3.1 is not supported to build computer vision apps(Metro Style computer vision applications) using windows 8's winRT APIs.

Any one having any idea about the release of new openCV version and its support for Windows 8???

Comment: Was Windows 8 officially released? Anyway, I'm sure you can get your answer in the OpenCV mailing list.

Comment: no but...yeah mailing list will a better source...

Comment: There is a .Net wrapper for opencv http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page which migth help

Comment: @Martin, if OpenCV doesn't work, it is probably because it is using APIs that are not part of the Metro style SDK.  A .Net wrapper won't alleviate that issue.  The library will have to be modified to use the newer API surface.